# Shape of universe from the metric's scalar factor

Tags: general-relativity

I am trying to understand FRW model and how one interpreted it. I missed a lecture and I am now trying to go through a friends notes. The teacher presented this metric as an example 
$$ds^2=-dt^2+\frac{t}{c}(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2) $$
where $c$ is a constant. He then states what type of geometry the universe has: flat, closed or opened. I don't understand how I can determine that.

I know that $a=\sqrt{\frac{t}{c}}$ and then the Hubble constant is  $H=\frac{1}{2t}$. One way to see the criteria for the different cases are $k\geq 0$ closed, $k= 0$ flat or $k\leq0 $ for open.  Where $k$ is form the Friedmann equation 
$$H^2=\frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho + \frac{k}{a^2} $$
and $\rho$ is the matter density.

I don't know how to prove it mathematically but my reasoning is that it cannot be closed. Because $t$ will continue to grow so the universe must be expanding. How to narrow it done further escapes me now.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}$
$\newcommand{\vect}[1]{{\bf #1}}$

There are many things going on there

> Cosmological principle

In general a metric of the form

$$
\dd s^2 = c^2\dd t^2 - a^2(t) \dd \vect{x}^2 \tag{1}
$$

Satisfies that the [cosmological principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_principle): universe is homogeneous an isotropic. In fact, imagine that $t$ is fixed, the effect of $a(t)$ is just "stretching" the coordinates, so if the universe satisfies the cosmological principle at a given time, it will follow it at any time.

Now, if the universe is to be homogeneous, its curvature $\kappa$ must be the same everywhere. There are only a handful of geometries that satisfy this constraint, one is the plane ($\kappa = 0$), other is the sphere ($\kappa = +1$) and finally an hyperbolic universe ($\kappa = -1$). Note that I deliberately used $\kappa = \pm 1$, because the metric can be scaled through the factor $a$ in Eq. (1), so the actual value of the curvature is unimportant.

The most general [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) for an universe that follows the cosmological principle is

$$
\dd s^2 = c^2 \dd t^2 -a^2 \left(\frac{1}{1 - \kappa r^2} \dd r^2 + r^2\dd \Omega^2\right) \tag{2}
$$

> Einstein's field equations

The equations that describe the coupled evolution of the spacetime geometry and its content [are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations)

$$
R_{\mu\nu} -\frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu} + \Lambda g_{\mu\nu} = \frac{8\pi G}{c^4}T_{\mu\nu} \tag{3}
$$

where $R_{\mu\nu}$ is the [Ricci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature) curvature tensor, $R$ the scalar curvature $R = R^\mu_\mu$, $g_{\mu\nu}$ the metric tensor, which can be directly extracted from Eq. (2) $\dd s^2 = g_{\mu\nu}\dd x^\mu \dd x^\nu$, $\Lambda$ the cosmological constant and $T_{\mu\nu}$ the [stress-energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) tensor which contains information about the physical content of the universe, for example $T^{00} = \rho$

This equation can be then explicitly written in terms of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ which results in a relation between the geometry $\kappa$ and the energy content $\rho c^2$ of the universe. The result is what we know as [Friedmann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations)

$$
 \frac{\dot{a}^2 + \kappa c^2}{a^2} = \frac{8 \pi G \rho + \Lambda c^2}{3} \tag{4}
$$

which is the result of calculating the 00 component of Eq. (3). If you take the trace instead, you get

$$
\frac{\ddot{a}}{a} =  -\frac{4 \pi G}{3}\left(\rho+\frac{3p}{c^2}\right) + \frac{\Lambda c^2}{3} \tag{5}
$$

Set $\Lambda = 0$ in Eq. (4) and you will conclude about the dynamics of $a$ in terms of the geometry $\kappa$ and the density $\rho$

> The fate of the universe

Let us consider for instance a universe for which $\Lambda =0$ and define

$$
\rho_c = \frac{3H^2}{8\pi G} ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ H = \frac{\dot{a}}{a}
$$

You can see that Eq. (4) becomes

$$
1 = \frac{\rho}{\rho_c} - \frac{\kappa c^2}{a^2H^2} \tag{5}
$$

which can be solved for $\kappa$

$$
\kappa = \frac{a^2 H^2}{c^2}\left(\frac{\rho}{\rho_c} - 1\right)
$$

This establishes a clear connection between density and geometry

1. $\rho > \rho_c$, then $\kappa > 0$ and the universe has spherical geometry (closed)
2. $\rho < \rho_c$ then $\kappa> 0$ and the universe has hyperbolical geometry (open)
3. $\rho = \rho_c$ in this case $k = 0$, which corresponds to the Euclidean flat space

Comment: Thanks. It is a very clear presentation of the theory. But I am afraid I still don't understand. In the Eq.(4) I sill have two unknowns, both $\rho$ and $\kappa$. So how can I conclude what $\kappa$ is?

Comment: @Orvar I extended my answer, hopefully it makes more sense now

Comment: I am afraid I still don't understand. What you have written is as far as I have been able to go myself. But as I still don't what $\rho$ is I just don't understand how  I should proceed.

Comment: @Orvar Right below Eq. (3) I mention that $\rho c^2$ is the energy density of the universe. Imagine a universe dominated only by matter, in this case $\rho$ means how many grams of matter per cubic meter of universe you have

Comment: What I meant was I don't know how to calculate what $\rho$ is. I think i know what it means physically: it is the combination of the density for dust, matter and vacuum. Or did you mean that I should calculate $R_{00}$ and $R$ and use the equation? Is there not a better way?

Comment: @Orvar I see, it depends on the type of component you're talking about. If it is dust then $\rho_m(a) = \rho_{m,0}a^{-3}$, if its radiation $\rho_\gamma(a) = \rho_{\gamma,0}a^{-4}$, for vacuum $\rho_{\Lambda}(a) = \rho_{\Lambda,0}$

Comment: I don't know what type is the dominant one, I think part of the point of the example was to figure that out as well.

Comment: @Orvar Perhaps it was me that didn't understand the question then. The last expression above shows how the density dictates the geometry and, therefore, the dynamics of the universe. The term $\rho$ can be the result of of the contribution of several components, each with a different behavior, but at the end, their sum dictates the value of $\kappa$

Comment: So is there no way to determine $\kappa$ without knowing $\rho$? If there are none, then he might just have told a physical reason for its geometry.

Comment: @Orvar Not from this set of arguments, but there are other ways. Imagine you draw a *really big* triangle. If the the result of adding up the angles is $\pi$ then $\kappa = 0$, $>\pi$ if $\kappa > 0$ and $<\pi$ if $\kappa < 0$

Comment: Okej, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to determine the shape then the one you provided is to look at the density $\rho$.  The different cases would then be:

for closed  $$\rho \geq \frac{3H^2}{8\pi G} $$ 
for open
$$\rho \leq \frac{3H^2}{8\pi G} $$
and flat

$$\rho=\frac{3H^2}{8\pi G} $$

Answer (score 1):

**Meaning of Closed, Open and Flat Universe**

Let us start with the simple definitions of a closed, open and flat universe. A closed universe is by definition one with $k=-1$, a flat universe is one with $k=0$ and an open universe is one $k=1$ regardless of what is happening to that universe.

**The Different Types of Density**

Their are three main types of density in the universe: 
$$ 
\newcommand{\p}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} \newcommand{\f}[2]{\frac{ #1}{ #2}} \newcommand{\l}[0]{\left(} \newcommand{\r}[0]{\right)} \newcommand{\mean}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}\newcommand{\e}[0]{\varepsilon} \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}
 \begin{align} \text{Matter (non-relativistic):}~~ & \rho_M=\f{\rho_{M,0}}{a^3} \\ \text{Radiation:}~~ & \rho_R=\f{\rho_{R,0}}{a^4} \\ \text{Vacuum:}~~ &  \rho_V=\rho_{V,0}\end{align}$$
where the last of these is assuming that the cosmological constant is infact constant.

**With $\rho_V \ne 0$**

With the vacuum density things get complicated, you can have a closed universe ($k=-1$) which is accelerating, a flat universe $k=0$ that recollapses etc. There is a nice picture of the different regions in 'An introduction to modern cosmology' by A.Liddle pg54 if you can get your hands on it.

**With $\rho_V=0$**

Things are a little nice a flat universe $k=0$ has $H\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$, a closed universe recollapses and an open universe expands forever. The dynamical evolution equation states that:
$$\dot a^2-\f{8\pi G \rho a^2}{3}=-k\tag{1}$$
now if $\dot a=0$ we have: 
$$a^2=\f{3k}{8\pi G \rho}$$
if $k=-1$ this has no solution and thus $\dot a$ will never pass through zero, and the universe must keep expanding forever. If $k=1$ this does has a solution and their will be a point where $\dot a=0$ and thus we can except the universe to collapse*.  If $k=0$ then going back to equation (1) we can see that since $\rho$ goes like $a^{-3}$ (at least) the only place $\dot a=0$ is at $a=\infty$ thus in this case we get a universe which only stops expanding at $a=\infty$ (which must correspond to $t=\infty$).